# Creating Kendo Grid in Aurelia TypeScript

Tags: typescript, kendo-grid, aurelia

I'm trying to use Kendo Grid in Aurelia using TypeScript, but I keep getting a error when I try to initialize it.

```
/// <reference path="../../../../vendors/Kendoui/typescript/kendo.all.d.ts" />

export class Test
{
    attached()
    {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid();
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is `Unhandled rejection TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I have looked at using Aurelia-Kendo-bridge, but for performance reasons, I chose not to use it.

Comment: I've written a blog that might interest you about integrating third party libraries into Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop

Comment: Are you sure the perf reasons are related to the bridge, and not kendo itself? If so, I would like to know what issues you encountered. Disclaimer: I'm one of the bridge's maintainers

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the aurelia-kendoui-bridge project: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-kendoui-bridge
This is an example from their component catalog:

```
<template>
  <ak-grid k-data-source.bind="datasource"
          k-pageable.bind="{ refresh: true, pageSizes: true, buttonCount: 10 }"
          k-sortable.bind="true">
    <!-- Column definitions in HTML -->
    <ak-col k-title="Contact Name" k-field="ContactName">
      <ak-template>
        <!-- Column templates directly in your markup - where they belong! -->
        <div class="customer-photo" style="background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/${CustomerID}.jpg);"></div>
        <!-- Use Aurelia binding features like interpolation, value converters and binding behaviors -->
        <div class="customer-name">${ContactName}</div>
      </ak-template>
    </ak-col>
    <ak-col k-title="Contact Title" k-field="ContactTitle"></ak-col>
    <ak-col k-title="Company Name" k-field="CompanyName"></ak-col>
    <ak-col k-field="Country"></ak-col>
  </ak-grid>
</template>
```

And the ViewModel:

```
export class ViewModel {
  datasource = {
    type: 'odata',
    transport: {
      read: '//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers'
    },
    pageSize: 5
  };
}
```

As per your original question, you're probably not importing Kendo. Put an import statement at the top of your viewmodel file:

```
import './path/to/kendo-ui.js';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Manuel, I have looked at this already and even got it working, but due to performance issues, I will not be looking to use it for now.

Answer (score 1):

How are you importing kendo? I wanted to use es2015 and systemJS bu later switched to importing the js files manually in my index page. I don't import all the widgets tough, to reduce size. Ofcourse doing it my way may mean that the kendo lib will be loaded upfront istead of when its required first.